# How do I insert something into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

On a previous page I have a textbox. Now the user enters in a number in that textbox and when the user submits the form it is posted into the next page. But what I want to know is how can I insert the number , into the database and do I place this code on the previous page when the textbox is or the next page where the number is posted?

In other words when user enters in a number in the textbox and submits the form, it navigates the user to the next page and displays the number on the next page but also inserts the number in the database.

The name of the table in the database is called 'Session' and the name of the field is 'TotalMarks'

Below is the textbox on the previous page where user enters in a number:

```
<input type="text" id="txtMarks" name="textMarks" />
```

Below is the php code for the number which is posted into the next page:

```
if (isset($_POST['textMarks'])) {

$_SESSION['textMarks'] = $_POST['textMarks'];

}
```

Comment: You have absolutely no idea what you are doing. Read some php tutorials.

Comment: Okay, so we know how your HTML and PHP look.  What about your database?  What database server software is it?  Is your database authentication working?  Have you tried reading any documentation on this, or are you hoping to use StackOverflow in place of a tutorial?

Comment: I am using MYSQL phpadmin, I do know about connecting to database and all that, I have done some code on creating queries to look up info from the database in a php application. I just did not know how to insert values in a database :) I know the code to connect to the database and all that. I just need to know though does the INSERT code go on the previous page where the textbox is or the next page where the details have been posted?

Comment: The INSERT code goes where your form submits. Only there is the $_POST value!

Comment: Everybody, Thanks for your help :) I will work on this, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mysql code is standard, you just need to execute with with mysql_query

example to go on next page after submitting the form(not tested):

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","databaseusername","databasepassword");
 mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

 $textmarks=$_POST['textMarks'];

 $sql = "insert into session (totalmarks) values ('$textmarks')";
 mysql_query($sql,$con);

 mysql_close($con);
```

I hope this helps.

Also read tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Good Luck.

Comment: Unsafe vunerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

The query would be:

```
INSERT INTO Session (TotalMarks) VALUES ('your value')
```

But you need to have a connection to your database first. Maybe look for a simple php/mysql tutorial (for example: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql). And be sure to be aware of Mysql Injection and how to avoid it!

Comment: I do know about connections to a database, I just did not know what the code is for inserting data into a database from a php page :) Thanks

Comment: Will it be best to put this code in the next page after form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql as the DB server , you shall need the php-mysql bridge

first , 
create a new connection by authentication:

```
$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$user,$password);
```

then use this connection resource object to select your database

```
mysql_select_db($databaseName,$con);
```

then perform your query on the database

```
mysql_query("insert into table_name values(\"$_POST[textMarks]\")");
```

Comment: I do know how to connect to the database :) All I want to know now is that does this code need to be placed on the previous page below thew form, or in the next page where the details are displayed?

Comment: you do it in 2 ways:
1) Take the value from the form in the same and store the session and make the DB entry in the same page . then you redirect to the next page  and print the value there using the session value

2) Set the action of the form to the next page itself .. write the code for the DB entry in the next page and then there would be no need for the session

Comment: I am thinking of doing it the first way, put the  DB code in the first page so that when form is submitted, it will post details in database and then post session in next page, last question, does DB code go below or above the form (where the textbox is)

Comment: Its better to put on top .. You're isset condition will decide the execution  if you are putting in the first page itself

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what database, but presuming MySQL, it would be so:

```
 if(isset($_POST['textMarks'])) {
     if(!mysql_connect(localhost,'username','password')) {
         die("cannot connect with the sql server");
     }

     if(!mysql_select_db($database)) {
         die("cannot connect with the database");
     }

     $myVar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textMarks']); // for security
     $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO Session('TotalMarks') VALUES ('{$myVar}')"; // qry
     mysql_query($sqlquery); // execute
 }
```

Comment: Small update in order, as the mysql_real_escape_string function needs a mysql server connection.